# Row selection and data processing in rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow-2

I am working with `JSF2.0`, `Spring-Webflow2.3.1` and `richfaces4.2.3`. 
I have got a `rich:extendedDataTable` which will show a list of data(There is no button present inside it). 
I need to implement ->

- double click on a row to get the details in a separate screen.
- Select a row and click on "View Details" button, which will also show me the details in the separate screen.

I am able to take out the row id, but i need to get the id field provided in the object to fetch the data. How will i make this possible using `spring-webflow`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample example as the second requirement
Select a row and click on "View Details" button, which will show the details in the separate screen.
I assume that

1. Your pojo Class name is **"YouPojoClass.java"**
2. Your pojo Class have **(member1,member2,code) fields**
3. Your data set of extendedDataTable will be get from **yourFirstController.rowVariableList** "List of YouPojoClass"
4. Your first page controller name "**yourFirstController.java**"
5. Your second page name is "**secondPage.xhtml**"

// In your first page screen

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="rowVariablepliersTable"
    value="#{yourFirstController.dataModel}" var="rowVariable">

    <rich:column width="300px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="member1" />            
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rowVariable.member1}" />
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column width="300px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="member2" />            
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rowVariable.member2}" />
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column width="90px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="view" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandButton 
            title="view" 
            value="view"
            action="#{yourFirstController.edit(rowVariable)}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

// In your first page controller

```
public String view(YouPojoClass rowVariable) {      
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    requestMap.put("SELECTED_ITEM_ID", rowVariable.getCode());  
    return "secondPage";
}
```

// In your second page controller

```
public void postConstruct() {
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    String SELECTED_ITEM_ID = requestMap.get("SELECTED_ITEM_ID");
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, there is no button within the datatable, there is only a single button ("view Details") outside the rich:extendedDataTable.

Comment: Then your `selectionMode` property of your `extendedDataTable`  must be `single`

Comment: As per your implementation, each row will have one `h:commandButton`and the action is made through this button. But for me no such button should be used. :( 
Also, here i should use `yourPojoClass.id` as the `selectedRowId`.